# for loops nested in R

Tags: r, loops, repeat

I have a dataset `dt`, it stored list dataset names, I need to use them to create some new datasets with select some variables, then I use the dataset I just created, repeat the same process .....

The first row and second row were data available.
Then use data available to create a new data.
Then use data just create to create a new data

The final output was list of datasets

I appreciated any helps or suggestions.

```
dt <- data.frame(name = c("mtcars","iris", "mtcars_new","mtcars_new_1"),
                 data_source = c("mtcars","iris", "mtcars","mtcars_new"),
                 variable = c("","","mpg,cyl,am,hp","mpg,cyl"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> dt
          name data_source      variable
1       mtcars      mtcars              
2         iris        iris              
3   mtcars_new      mtcars mpg,cyl,am,hp
4 mtcars_new_1  mtcars_new       mpg,cyl


dt_list <- list(mtcars, iris)
names(dt_list ) <- c("mtcars","iris")


# The final list of datasets
final_dt <- list(mtcars, iris,  mtcars_new, mtcars_new_1)
```

So far if I wrote a loop like that, I got only `mtcars_new` dataset, but I don't know how to return to the list and continue looping to get `mtcars_new_1` and so on. I have many datasets, and I don't know how many times I should looping through nested data.

```
mtcars_new <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){
  if(dt$data_source[[i]] %in% names(dt_list) && !dt$name[[i]] %in% names(dt_list)){
    check <- eval(parse(text = dt$data_source[[i]]))
    var <- c(unlist(strsplit(dt$variable[[i]],",")))
    mtcars_new <- check[, colnames(check) %in% var]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the desired output shown. Since the fourth loop uses the data created in the third loop, you need to have a way to append the results of each loop to a growing list of available data sets. Then within each loop find which one is the right starting data set from the available list.

```
dt <- data.frame(name = c("mtcars","iris", "mtcars_new","mtcars_new_1"),
                 data_source = c("mtcars","iris", "mtcars","mtcars_new"),
                 variable = c("","","mpg,cyl,am,hp","mpg,cyl"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

input_data_sets <- list(mtcars, iris)
names(input_data_sets) <- c("mtcars","iris")

final_data_sets <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  
  available_data_sets <- c(input_data_sets, final_data_sets)  #Grows a list of all available data sets
  num_to_use <- which(dt$data_source[[i]] == names(available_data_sets)) #finds the right list member to use

  temp <- available_data_sets[num_to_use][[1]]
  var <- c(unlist(strsplit(dt$variable[[i]],",")))
  
  temp <- list(subset(temp, select = var)) #keep only the desired variables
  names(temp) <- dt$name[i] #assign the name provided
  
  final_data_sets <- c(final_data_sets, temp) #add to list of final data sets which will be the output. Anything listed here will become part of the available list in the next loop
  
}
```

Comment: When you checked `which(dt$data_source[[i]] == names(available_data_sets))`, it returned `mtcars` and `iris` with 0 row, cuz `dt$variable` `= ""`.